# php : regex between strings not working correctly

Tags: php, regex

I need to retrieve value **6Lf4** , but its just returning array..what am i doing wrong?

```
  <?php
    $inputString = 'private="key" value="6Lf4" sent="yut"';
    $matches = array();
    preg_match_all('/key" value="(.*?)"/', $inputString, $matches);
    echo $matches[1];
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on http://ideone.com/vDV7yE, you'll want to use `$matches[1][0]` to get your string:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => key" value="6Lf4"
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6Lf4
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this pattern,

```
(?<=(value=")).*?(?=")
```

See **[Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Width Assertions.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)**

Answer (score 0):

Check here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

You'll want to do:

```
echo $matches[1][0];
```

This is because you're correct in using key 1 to get the parenthesized subpattern, but you want to get the first match of this type, so you need to get the value of THAT sub-array at index 0.

So you're halfway there, but you need to get the actual value inside the array that you're returning.